# How to pin git repos on github profile?

Tags: github

I am trying to pin some of my repos on my GitHub profile.
I tried this [tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile)

But I am not getting these options.

[image]

Here is what it is showing me.

[image]

I am not able to see and pin the remaining two repos.

Can someone help me with how to do that?

Comment: What happens if you enter the full name of the repo? Does it show up in the list?

Comment: No, it is not showing up even if I am entering the full name. But at the bottom, it is showing that 2 remaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pin your own repositories (owned by you, such as forks or manually created ones) or repositories which contain commits by you. Your linked [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile) is pretty clear about this in its first paragraph:

> You can pin a public repository *if you own* the repository or *you've made contributions* to the repository. *Commits to forks don't count as contributions, so you can't pin a fork that you don't own*. For more information, see "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)"
>
> You can pin any public gist you own.
>
> [emphasis mine]

If you need to find repositories of others, use bookmarks in your browser.

Comment: Let's say, A repo is created by someone else but I am constantly contributing to that repo. Can I pin that?

Comment: As you can see I am able to pin this repo `AnushaPhyrdha/LanundryServices` which is created by someone else;

Comment: @AshutoshYadav did you fork `AnushaPhyrdha/LanundryServices`? I can only pin my own repositories or forked repositories. Perhaps this is determined by having commits in those repositories? Or having to have them forked in the past?

Comment: I haven't forked. But I got an invitation to contribute to that Repo. And I have one more repo for which I got an invitation and I am contributing to that Repo too. but I am not able to pin that Repo.

Comment: @AshutoshYadav is the email address you used to contribute linked to your account? Are the repos original (non-fork) repos? Have you checked the first link from the doc?